# Technical specs for master to be shown at FilmFestival

Tags: master, filmfestival, theater

Hi again,

Thanks to Shaun Farley and Tim Prebble who answered to my previous question, I figured out I must go into a good studio to be certain about the mixing coming from Pro-tools.
Now...because I have no more money to spend (I produced my first documentary on my own)...fortunately I have a friend who has access to a good studio (where they dub american movies) for free.

This guy needs to know exactly which are the technical specs (in therms of -db...or whatever) for the masters: DVD and Beta sp (the festival that selected my documentary wants a DVD too...in case of problems with Beta sp).

What are exactly the specs for masters (DVD and Beta sp) to go to a Theater (filmfestival)?

Sorry again for my ignorance...but maybe it will be helpful to somebodyelse too.
Thanx a lot. Gio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao Gio
As Tim already answered in the other question, those are the specs for laying back to BetaSP (even if some tv network, in Italy have other specs too).

All the theater (or most of them) have a Dolby certification: this is the only standard specs regarding level that you can follow (these should be guaranteed if you print a film copy or go with DCP).

Unfortunately most of the theater (at least here in Italy) doesn't have a standard alignment when projecting from DVD or BetaSP, even if you follow all the standard specification: it really depends on the projectionist.

Hope it helps

Davide

Comment: Ciao e grazie Davide...I really want to know more about this all, here in Rome it's confusing..lots of different opinions. It's my first direction and my first final mixage (I've always done sound design that has been mixed from somebodyelse). It's gonna sound bizarre..but what does DCP mean?

Comment: DCP means Digital Cinema Package: it's a digital file format to deliver movie to theaters instead of the printed copy.

Yes, in Roma everybody has a different opinion, everybody knows something better than everyone else ;)
If the room where you'll mix is properly calibrated and the mixer have some experience in mixing for cinema and/or television, there shouldn't be any problem... but my advise is: if you have any money to spend, you should go and have your doc mixed in one of the audio-post studios (Technicolor Sound Services(International recording) or Fonoroma or Cinecittà).


Comment: I was forgetting....nice that recording into the tunnel below Termini station!